# Mongoose find where using modulus

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a find query that looks something like this

```
Message.find({active: true},function(err,docs){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return true;
  }
  console.log(docs);
  for(i in docs){
    if(minutes % docs[i].interval === 0){
      chatBot.say(config.channels[0], docs[i].message);
    }
  }
});
```

Here I am looking up all messages that are active, once I've got those I loop over each to see if the interval field is equal to a modulus of a minutes variable that increases each minute.

How would I not only search by active messages but also ones that meet the modulus requirement so I don't have to get messages returned that don't match what I want.

I'm pretty new to mongoose so I've tried googling but I'm not really sure how I can make this query work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work this way

```
Message.find({active: true}).$where(minutes+' % this.interval === 0').exec(function(err,docs){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return true;
  }
  console.log(docs);
  if(docs.length > 0){
    for(i in docs){
      chatBot.say(config.channels[0], docs[i].message);
    }
  }
});
```

I found that there is a `.mod()` function but that puts the value from the document first before the mod number, and I needed it the other way around, so I found in the query documentation a way to run the query like this and that way I can get the numbers in the order I need them.